# What should I use for 3D graphics before OSX 10.11?

Tags: osx, 3d, macos

10.11 and on I use Metal, but what should I use for earlier versions? On Xcode on a computer I have that has OSX 10.8.5, it didn't offer an OpenGL game template for OSX, only for iOS. It only offered SpriteKit. I'm not sure SpriteKit is ideal for 3D rendering.

I don't want to use a game engine, those are bloated and slow, I want to use a low-level graphics API, so what's the best alternative to Metal for versions that came before it?

Answer (score 1):

Macs come with a graph package called Grapher. It usually resides in the Utilities Folder.  Its a pretty bare bones app and will plot equations or points. You may want to play with this app and see if it meets your needs.

To find it go to a Finder window and click on Go in the menu bar. That opens another menu and at the bottom of that list is Utilities. Click on this.

Comment: In that case, what technology was used to create Grapher

Comment: I don't know. All that was installed on my drive was the Mac application. I suppose it was writen in Objective C or maybe Swift. But the app should be on your machine in the utilities folder.  The source code was not supplied and is most likely proprietary.

Comment: Grapher is an application. it runs on a Mac computer. Its not an API or development environment. it is just an application like Pages or Preview.

Comment: An API is what I am looking for